# Descargar archivos de mi Servidor FTP

Tags: java, ftp

Tengo un servidor FTP del cual necesito descargar unas imágenes.

Ya busqué varios códigos en Internet donde me dicen que baje miles de librerías, muestran el código y ninguno me funciona.

Estoy haciendo esta aplicación con el lenguaje de programación Java en Netbeans.

El código que encontré en Internet:

```
package com.beingjavaguys.testftp;  

import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.net.SocketException;  
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;  

public class DownloadFile {  
 public static void main(String args[]) {  

  // get an ftpClient object  
  FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();  
  FileOutputStream fos = null;  

  try {  
   // pass directory path on server to connect  
   ftpClient.connect("nagesh12.5gbfree.com");  

   // pass username and password, returned true if authentication is  
   // successful  
   boolean login = ftpClient.login("username", "password");  

   if (login) {  
    System.out.println("Connection established...");  

    fos = new FileOutputStream("files/downloadedFile.txt");  
    boolean download = ftpClient.retrieveFile("uploadedFile.txt",  
      fos);  
    if (download) {  
     System.out.println("File downloaded successfully !");  
    } else {  
     System.out.println("Error in downloading file !");  
    }  

    // logout the user, returned true if logout successfully  
    boolean logout = ftpClient.logout();  
    if (logout) {  
     System.out.println("Connection close...");  
    }  
   } else {  
    System.out.println("Connection fail...");  
   }  

  } catch (SocketException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  } catch (IOException e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
  } finally {  
   try {  
    ftpClient.disconnect();  
   } catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
   }  
  }  
 }  
}
```

Comment: Hola Marcus, Bienvenido a SO en Español, podrias agregar que librerias ya has intentado usar y el codigo que utilizaste, quiza los colaboradores del sitio te recomienden alguna libreria, ya que es mas facil usar algo que ya existe, pero comentanos que has usasdo, asi te podemos ayudar mas :)

Comment: Gracias por agregar la info, que error te da, manda alguna excepcion? o que mensaje te manda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.html)

El codigo seria parecido a:

```
FTPClient cliente = new FTPClient();//Iniciamos el cliente del FTP
FileOutputStream stream = null;

client.connect("192.168.0.tuIP");
client.login("usuario", "pass");

String archivo = "/archivo.doc";
stream = new FileOutputStream("archivoLocal");

cliente.retrieveFile(archivo, stream);//pone el archivo en tu stream
stream.close();
cliente.disconnect();
```

El import seria a `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`

[Documentación de FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

Comment: Una pregunta, jasilva.
La String archivo es la ruta del archivo en el FTP?

Comment: @MarcusDeclementi Si, por ejemplo `/carpeta1/subcarpeta/archivo.xml`

Comment: No me funciona. Pongo la ruta y aún así no me funciona.
Hay alguna manera de mandarte un mensaje privado para que me puedas ayudar?

Comment: @MarcusDeclementi Pero que error te da? Asi estamos un poco a ciegas

Comment: El código que te "posteé" me da este error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: \public_html\prueba\Nuevodocumentodetexto.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

Comment: Ok, muy bien, en que linea da esa excepcion?

Comment: Marca el error en la línea 30

Comment: La linea 30 del codigo que publicas no coicide con alguna que provoque ese error, podrias copiar la copiar la linea aqui

Comment: fos = new FileOutputStream("prueba/Nuevodocumentodetexto.txt");

Comment: @MarcusDeclementi Parece que el problema es que no se puede crear el archivo, [por alguna razon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29), parece que tu SO es un linux o un unix por las rutas, que pasa si pones la ruta absoluta del archivo `new FileOutputStream("/home/usario/prueba/Nuevodocumentodetexto.txt");`

Comment: Tampoco así pueo hacerlo, pero ahora que lo mencionas, creo que mi FTP está en Linux. En ese caso me tendré que poner en contacto con mi serviio de hosting para que me ayuden con el "usuario".

Comment: @MarcusDeclementi Que el FTP este en linux es trasparente gracias al protocolo, lo importante es tu equipo en el que ejecutas tu programa , ya que esa linia indica que se va a crear un archivo en TU equipo ¿Que SO tienes en tu equipo, windows, mac linux, otro unix?

Comment: Windows 7.

El archivo se crea, pero en blanco.

Comment: @jasilva Rechacé una edición sugerida, lo que sugieren es cambiar `cliente` por `client`, pero eso quedaría a tu decisión y no del que lo sugiere.

Answer (score 2):

El codigo que me funciona es el siguiente:

```
private static String ip = "ftp.xxx.xx";
private static String user = "user";
private static String pass = "password";
private static String localFileDownload = "C:\\Users\\userd\\Desktop\\archivo.xlsx";
private static String hostFile="/archivo.xlsx";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
    conectar(ip,user,pass);
    desrcargarArchivoFTP(localFileDownload, hostFile);
    desconectar();
}    

public static void conectar(String ip, String user, String pass) throws SocketException, IOException{
    ftp = new FTPClient();
    ftp.connect(ip);

    if(ftp.login(user, pass))
        System.out.println("login OK");
    else
        System.out.println("login Error");
}

public static void desrcargarArchivoFTP(String localFile, String hostFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    //fos = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
    BufferedOutputStream buffOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));
    if(ftp.retrieveFile(hostFile, buffOut))
        System.out.println("Descarga correcta");
    else
        System.out.println("Error Descarga");

    buffOut.close();
    //fos.close();
}
```